# NextJs Metadata in "use client"

Tags: javascript, next.js, metadata, next.js14

So the problem is I have a product page in which I'm getting metadata for that particular product page from backend i.e. from database using an API. I have to use a custom hook to fetch data from that API, Now the Problem is I can't use that metadata from the "use client" directive.

I can't share my whole code As it's 500+ lines so here's a glimpse what I am trying to do!

```
"use client"
import React from "react";
import useGetData from "./useGetData";

const Page = () => {
   const { data } = useGetData();
   return (
      <div>
      Some use of {data}
      </div>
   );
}

export default Page;

const GenerateMetaDataTags = () => {
  const { propId } = useParams();
  const { data, loading, error } = useGetData(propId);
  const metaData = {};

  data.forEach((ele) => {
    metaData[ele.name] = ele.content;
  });

  if (!loading) {
    return metaData;
  }
};

export const metadata = GenerateMetaDataTags();
```

I want this Data to update on the client side after fetching from the database.

I tried a lot of different approaches like using layout.js and all but I have to use hook to get the data from database and the hook will always need the "use client";

Comment: Why do you need a hook to get data from the database? Can you use a server action instead? This would give you client-side updates if you tag and revalidate your fetch call in the data cache.

Comment: Still, It will need a "use client" tag to reflect changes in the page.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code here, you have fetched the meta data in `metadata`. Now you might need to populate it in the return of the `Page` method. Also consider calling `GenerateMetaDataTags()` before the return and consider removing the call `export const metadata = GenerateMetaDataTags();` in the last line. When you say metadata, I am assuming it is the data in the `meta` tags which goes in the `Head` component like.

```
import Head from 'next/head'

...
...
const Page = () => {
   const { data } = useGetData();

   const metadata = GenerateMetaDataTags();

  return (
<>
    <Head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000" />
      <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicon/browserconfig.xml" />
      <meta name="ele1" content={metaData["ele1"]} />
      <meta name="ele2" content={metaData["ele2"]} />
    </Head>

    <SomeComponent>
     <div>
      Some use of {data}
     </div>
    </SomeComponent>

</>);
}
...
...
```

You can read more about rendering for [pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering) router, or for [app](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering) router.

Comment: Doesn't works with App Router

Answer (score 0):

i'm facing the same problem, i tried several approach without success, i'm using next js 14 and mongodb with several nested routes, so the only clean way to fetch the data is client side ( using "use client" for useeffect ), now all pages work very well except the seo part :) , because if you use 'use client' within the app router you can't use the export const metadata or the  .

if they had let the nextseo, the head component ... it was very easy to deal with seo

Answer (score -1):

as the docs says you cannot generate metadata in a client component.

Comment: I know that. I asked here for a different approach.